# What is the difference between these DNS? Which one is more NSA-proof?

Tags: privacy, dns, anonymity

What is the difference between these DNS servers: `8.26.56.26`/`8.20.247.20` vs `156.154.70.22`/`156.154.71.22`

Main purpose of using is top anonymity and privacy and security.

thnx

Answer (score 2):

As is your question does not make a lot of sense, and is not necessarily very on-topic here.

First, do you think everyone knows these IP addresses? Why not speaking directly about the organizations you are speaking about?

Now, the choice you present is not really a choice: whatever you choose, you need to remember that DNS queries and replies are sent by default in the clear, and that you need to trust the recursive DNS you choose as it obviously has a detail about all your queries.
So any actor with enough power could easily abuse these 2 facts.

If you want to gain more "privacy"  and "security" you should instead investigate the following in no specific order and sometimes used together:

- use your own local recursive nameserver
- use a distant one you trust (or you manage yourself) through DNS over TLS
- or some as previous but with DNS over HTTPS
- use a recursive nameserver that implements QNAME minimization in order to send less information to each authoritative nameserver during the resolution.

Comment: Hi Patrick,Could you send me a tutorial link that can cover the mentioned approach altogether please? What DNS server do you suggest to me to use, initially until I can sort out a secure one lie you mentioned?

Comment: @PrincessMileena you want a single link that explains all those points in one place? I think you can use those descriptions to find the many, many documents online that explains them all in depth.